# ¿Como conseguir datos de otras tablas y añadirlas a una tabla diferente?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy haciendo un sistema de inventarios y tengo un problema. Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario de pedidos. El problema es que no se como conseguir los datos de otros formularios, en este caso lo que necesito conseguir son los campos id Usuario y Proveedor_numeroIdent.

Esta es la tabla de pedidos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que con el formulario de pedidos se añadan esos campos que estan en la tabla.

Pero no se como obtener la id del usuario y el numero de identificación del proveedor.

Este es el código del formulario:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang ="es">
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title> Pedido</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/estilos_pedido.css">
</head>
  <body>
   <h1><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="" class="logo"></h1>

    <form action ="Pedido.php" method ="post" class= "form-register">

        <h2 class = "form__titulo"> Pedido</h2>
        <div class = "contenedor-inputs">

            <input type ="number" name ="numero" placeholder ="Numero" class = "input-48"  required> 
            <input type ="date" name ="fechacreacion" placeholder ="Fecha creacion" class = "input-48" required> 

            <input type ="date" name ="fechavencimiento" placeholder ="Fecha vencimiento" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="text" name ="condiciones" placeholder ="Condiciones" class = "input-48" required> 

            <input type ="number" name ="subtotal" placeholder ="Subtotal" class = "input-48" required> 

            <input type ="number" name ="iva" placeholder ="IVA" class = "input-48" required> 
            <input type ="number" name ="total" placeholder ="Total" class = "input-100" required > 

            <input type ="text" name ="observaciones" placeholder ="Observaciones" class = "input-100" required >    




            <input type ="submit" value ="enviar pedido" class = "btn-enviar">

        <p> </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código php:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';



$numero = $_POST["numero"];

$fechac = $_POST["fechacreacion"];

$fechav = $_POST["fechavencimiento"];

$con = $_POST["condiciones"];

$sub = $_POST["subtotal"];

$iva = $_POST["iva"];

$total = $_POST["total"];

$observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"];



$insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if(!$resultado){
 echo mysqli_error($conexion);

}
else
{
echo 'Se ha llenado el formulario con exito';

}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Esto es lo que contiene la tabla proveedores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que cuando inserte los datos pueda obtener el id del usuario que ya esta logueado.

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola denuevo jeje, puedes agregar como haces el Login de los usuarios? Lo otro que seria bueno que explicaras, es que contiene la tabla Proveedores y donde los ocupas en tu aplicacion.

Comment: <?php

//conectar a la base de datos
include 'configuracion.php';

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username='$usuario' and contrasena='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($filas > 0){
    header("location:menu.html"); 
}
else{
    echo "Error en la autentificacion";
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);

?> así es como hago el login de los usuarios. Ya edite mi pregunta y puse la imagen de lo que contiene la tabla proveedores

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de 2 formas

Primera: Crea una variable de session en PHP cuando el usuario se loguee. De tal forma que cuando la necesites la uses. Debes considerar el tiempo de session en el servidor.

Aquí tienes más información

http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

La segunda que no tiene el problema de la variable de session en servidor, es:

En el contexto (parte de la aplicación que lo necesites, crea una variable global en javasript

un script ej: app.js

ahi defines:

```
session = {
    idUsuario: '',
    idProveedor: ''
};
```

En el contexto de la app o en la parte donde accesas ese dato del servidor, lo guardas en la variable de session, asi:

```
session.idUsuario = <>;
session.idProveedor = <>;
```

El corchete es la variable donde lo guardas, puede ser en un cuadro de texto hidden de un formulario o json que traes del servidor.

Luego los puedes asignar a cuadros de texto en formularios y enviarlos al servidor.

Espero haber sido lo bastante claro.

Saludos,